# Jenkins pipeline writeJSON throwing AccessDeniedException

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When calling writeJson in my pipeline, I am getting the below error:

java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/AAA/benchmarks/test/test.json
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:434)
at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Files.java:216)
at hudson.FilePath$WritePipe.invoke(FilePath.java:2326)
at hudson.FilePath$WritePipe.invoke(FilePath.java:2320)
at hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:3329)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at hudson.remoting.Engine$1.lambda$newThread$0(Engine.java:117)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Following is my call to writeJSON

```
dir ("benchmarks/updated") {
    for(result in results) {
        echo "writing updates in file: ${result.file}"
        echo "result is: ${result}"
        writeJSON file: "${result.file}", json: result, pretty:4
    }
}
```

I made sure my file path and my json strings are fine, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was caused by creating a directory using

```
sh "mkdir -p mydir"
```

and then later in the pipeline calling:

```
dir ("mydir") {
   writeJSON file: "${result.file}", json: result, pretty:4
}
```

which caused the AccessDeniedException exception

simply removing the sh command and delegating the directory creation to the dir("mydir") fixed the issue